# Loading all static buffers to video memory at startup?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on an Android game with openGL ES 2.0, and I have a set of 16 simple, nontextured meshes (15 vertices each) that I am going to draw up to 30 times per frame(on various locations) through the entire game.

Would it be benificial to buffer these meshes into video memory as an array at the start of my application(or window initialization), and only send bufferoffset and MVP matrix to the sharers at each frame, or will this hog too much vmem(or make too little difference per frame) to be beneficial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will this hog too much vmem...?

16 meshes * 15 vertices * 3 floats per vertex (xyz) * 4 bytes per float ~= 3 ***kilobytes***.

I think you'll be fine.  Slap 'em in a VBO at startup and call it good.

Comment: Of course, thank you. I've been focusing a bit too much on the memory limits, and now I feel silly.